# PyTorch Inequality Gradient

Tags: pytorch

I wrote a PyTorch model roughly as follows:

```
import torch.nn as nn
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(64 * 64, 16), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(16, 32), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
        self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(32, 64), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
        self.layer4 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(64, 15), nn.Tanh())
    def forward(self, x):
        return (self.layer4(self.layer3(self.layer2(self.layer1(x)))) < 0).float()
```

Notice what I want to do: I want `forward` to return a tensor of 0s and 1s. However, this does not train, probably because the derivative of the inequality is zero.

How can I make a model like this one train, for example, if I want to do image segmentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you can't train something like `x<0`.
You should be fine even if you get rid of the `<0` part and use

```
    return self.layer4(self.layer3(self.layer2(self.layer1(x))))
```

as long as you are using the appropriate loss. I think what you would  want to use is `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`. In that case you should get the `Tanh` out of the last layer since `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` internally computes with sigmoid.
(There are options of using `nn.BCEloss()` with `sigmoid` at the last layer, or even stick with `Tanh`, but I don't think there's a reason to take the long way.)

So in the **training phase**, the neural network tries as hard as it could to fit the output to 0s and 1s. After that, it is the **testing phase** that you should take the output of the layer, and give it some kind of threshold to change the values to precisely 1s and 0s.(like you did `(output<0).float()`)

You will find useful sources if you search for `multilabel classification`.